# How to use a 2-column mapping file to assign data associated with one column in a second file to the other column in another file

Tags: bash

I have a mapping.txt that looks like this:

```
x1      yn
xd      y4
x5      y7
```

and file2 that looks like:

```
y4      0.1
y7      0.3
yn      0.7
```

I want to use the mapping.txt to get an output like this:

```
x1      0.7
xd      0.1
x5      0.3
```

So for instance: xd corresponds to y4 (mapping.txt) and so the value for y4 (0.1) is assigned to xd.

I can do this with some sorting and column manipulation, but I am looking for something that actually follows the same algorithm (with bash).

Comment: Isn't file1 redundant here? You don't seem to use the information in it or am I missing something?

Comment: yes. I will re-edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you walk through `file2` and store every line in an array, using the first column as index and the second one as value. Once this array is constructed, walk through `mapping.txt` and print the first column followed by the the array value of the element in the second column. This results in following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{maps[$1]=$2} NR!=FNR{print $1 "    " maps[$2]}' file2 mapping.txt
```

Or you could store this in an `awk` script:

```
# if first file (file2)
NR==FNR{
    # store column entries in array maps
    # key is the first column, value the second
    maps[$1] = $2
}
# if second file
NR!=FNR{
    # print first column and mapped value for second column
    print $1 "    " maps[$2]
}
```

Comment: No problem, leave a comment if you need more information or clarification about the mechanics of the script.

Comment: I have another similar problem, but the first column has quotes:
"xd", "x5" and so on in both mapping.txt and file2. I tried your awk script but it doesn't print the mapped values properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the quotes be removed? If so, add `{gsub(/"/, "", $1)}` before the first line of the script.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ join -1 2 -o 1.1,2.2 <(sort -k 2,2 mapping.txt) <(sort file2)
xd 0.1
x5 0.3
x1 0.7
```

`join` requires it's input files to be sorted on the join field, so I sort the mapping on its 2nd field, and file2 is sorted by the (default) first field.

The `-o` option controls the output: print out the first field from the first file and the second field from the second file

The `<(...)` syntax is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) -- they execute the contained `sort` commands and then `join` is able to process the output from something that looks like a file.

Comment: This is a great answer, never heard of the `join` command before, I'll definitely check that out!

Comment: It works perfect! 
If you could just teach me: does it do the proper sorting because of 1.1 and 2.2?

Comment: Added some more explanation in my answer